# Automatic script with CakePhp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm looking for some search tracks for my project.

First here what I'm using :

- software : C#
- web : CakePHP (PHP)

I'm trying to do a semi-automatic tool running both on desktop and web.
I have created a software in C# who uploads on my webserver (with CakePhp) a text file. The text file contains regular datas separed by `;`. I would like that this text file is processed by a php script and inserted in a database.

The purpose of my project is to allow users to retrieve their datas on the web ready to use.

Text files are upload in `/www/CakePHP/app/webroot/files/tickets/<id>/textfile.txt`

`<id>` is the id of the user who uploads the file

I thought of a cron job, for example, which will launch a script called "import.php" which, every night, would look at all the folders `<id>` and then treat and import the textfile.txt but I have no idea how to do it (with or even without CakePhp up)

Where can i create my `import.php` script to treat and import text files ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you read up on the CakePHP console and shell scripts (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html)?

Comment: yes but i don't know how to setup this, i'm using a shared server btw

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to execute script directly from upload path like:

```
30 2 * * * php /www/CakePHP/app/webroot/files/tickets/import.php
```

(2:30 AM example)